# Join all dataset

Tags: python, django

Have table in that I wanna show every B and C that has the same A.
If C has a B it should show it both on a row.
If C don't have a B, just show C.
If B don't have a C, just show B.

Is there any good way to join B and C so I get that result?
Can join them, but only if C and B is connected.

```
class A
Id

class B
id
Name
A.id

class C
id
Name

class E
Id
B.id
C.id
```

Comment: This is just to abstract

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
es = E.objects.all()
b_list = []
c_list = []
for each in es:
    print each.b.name, each.c.name
    b_list.append(each.b)
    c_list.append(each.c)
bs = B.objects.all()
cs = C.objects.all()
for each in bs:
    if each in b_list:
         continue
    print each.name
for each in cs:
    if each in c_list:
         continue
    print each.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and time you puy into this.
Solved it, but don't have the time to explain.